# Как сделать так чтобы автотесты не падали после авторизации. PageObject. Java + JUnit

Tags: java, test-automation

Учусь писать автотесты Java+JUnit с использованием PageObject.
Приложение состоит из первой страницы авторизации (LoginPage), после которой совершается переход на главную страницу (MainPage) и с нее переход на разные другие.
[image: Пример_1]

то есть получается, чтобы выполнить тесты для страницы MainPage, мне нужно зайти в систему, т.е выполнить тест успешной авторизации из LoginPageTest, иначе все дальнейшие тесты упадут. Ничего пока лучше не придумала как вызывать перед выполнением тестов из MainPageTest публичный метод из LoginPage, таким образом:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.successLogin("root","root");
```

[image: Пример_2]

[image: Пример_2]
Но поскольку Java я тоже только учу, насколько вообще адекватен данный подход? Или как должны реализовываться такие вещи?

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете вполне адекватный подход. Т.к. логин является предусловием для набора тестов, то логично разместить этот шаг в секции `@Before`.

P.S. - В методе `successLogin()` не обязательно вызывать методы через `this`.